# Linq Performance the Sum of Count is faster than Count 1 by 1?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

This work like a flash...

```
hits = s.hits + s.sound_track.Sum(S => S.SoundHistory.Count),
```

And this is very slow... unusable

```
Songs = s.sound_track.Select(s2 => new {s2.SoundHistory.Count},
```

If I not comment this line give

```
InnerException = {"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."}
```

Why? And can I do better? I need to show songs count and at end I can sum all Songs hits, but the first one is usable and this is not.

Comment: Maybe `name` and/or `id_song` are properties with expensive getters?

Comment: The second one should be instant, as it is using deferred execution, post the full example if you want decent answers.

Comment: Removed the name and id_song, same problem.@BenVoigt

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the first one sums the numbres, and the second creates objects. They are very different things. Don't you think?

How many songs do you have ? How Many fields? Where are you getting them ? DB ?

I'd guess that the Sum delegates to the DB and which will do a fast sum of the column and that is.

In the second one, you're fetching a whole bunch of objects, so you need to allocate memory for them, initialize them, etc ...

Comment: Thanks, but anyway now I can count the album hits like a all sounds hits, but I can put the songs hits by song to production...@Noctis

Comment: IF you have lazy loading enabled, your 2nd attempt will load all columns of all tables into memory. Try selecting specific values you need or try SelectMany. GL